# Unable to import MySQL Connector using PyCharm

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pymysql, mysql-connector-python

```
import mysql.connector
```

I was trying to make a database using python. I used the code shown below after the installation of `MySQL-connector-python` to the python interpreter, but the following output shows in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\coding\sql-course-materials\SQL Course Materials\mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "F:\coding\sql-course-materials\SQL Course Materials\mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package
```

Comment: Did you install using `pip install mysql-connector` or `pip3 install mysql-connector` if running Mac OS?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (2.2.9)
 .......................

Comment: I have already installed